# Change single qubit state in Q#

Tags: q#

I am starting with Q# and I would like to know how can I get the following qubit state:

```
0.8|0⟩ + 0.2|1⟩
```

from a qubit initialized as |0⟩.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a clarification that in order to have a properly-normalized state, you probably intend to create a state something like:
$\sqrt{0.8}  \left| 0 \right> + \sqrt{0.2} \left| 1 \right>$.
Here the probability of measuring $\left| 0 \right>$ is 0.8 and the probability of measuring $\left| 1 \right>$ is 0.2, when measuring in the computational basis.

Now, starting with a qubit in the $\left| 0 \right>$ state, you can just apply an [Ry operation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.ry) with the appropriate angle. You need to choose the angle such that $\cos({\theta}/{2}) = \sqrt{0.8}$. The [ArcCos function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.math.arccos) will help you here.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)